# ASP NET MVC Highcharts null pointer when adding series

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

Currently stuck trying to add data to a [Highcharts](http://dotnet.highcharts.com/) chart ASP NET MVC via the [official highcharts package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Highsoft.Highcharts/).

**ReportsController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Revenue()
        {
            List<double?> usaValues = new List<double?> {
                null, null, null, null, null, 6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
                1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
                27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
                26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
                24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
                22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
                10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104 };
            List<double?> russiaValues = new List<double?> {
                null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060, 1605, 2471, 3322,
                4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538, 11643, 13092, 14478,
                15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935, 30062, 32049,
                33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
                35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
                21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000 };
            List<AreaSeriesData> usaData = new List<AreaSeriesData>();
            List<AreaSeriesData> russiaData = new List<AreaSeriesData>();
            usaValues.ForEach(p => usaData.Add(new AreaSeriesData { Y = p }));
            russiaValues.ForEach(p => russiaData.Add(new AreaSeriesData { Y = p }));
            ViewData["usaData"] = usaData;
            ViewData["russiaData"] = russiaData;
            return View();
        }
```

**Revenue.cshtml**

```
@(Html.Highsoft().Highcharts(
                    new Highcharts
                    {
                        Chart = new Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts.Chart
                        {
                            Type = ChartType.Line
                        }
                        ,
                        Series = new List<Series>
                        {
                            new LineSeries
                            {
                                Name = "Tokyo",
                                Data = ViewData["usaData"] as 
   List<LineSeriesData>
                            }
                        }
                    }, "container"
            )
    )

<div id="container"></div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
}
```

When I remove the below "Series" section from the chart, the chart displays as an empty chart (correct behavior as per the highcharts.js version).

```
Series = new List<Series>
                        {
                            new LineSeries
                            {
                                Name = "Tokyo",
                                Data = ViewData["usaData"] as 
   List<LineSeriesData>
                            }
                        }
```

But when I add it back in a compilation error displays with no in IDE error code highlighting in VS2017.

The exception finds fault with this line

```
@(Html.Highsoft().Highcharts(
```

and exception details  highlighted in red as such

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the wrong datatype in the view (LineSeriesData instead of AreaSeriesData).

```
 List<AreaSeriesData> usaData = new List<AreaSeriesData>();  // <--- TYPE ---
 ...
 ViewData["usaData"] = usaData;
```

but in the view...

```
 Data = ViewData["usaData"] as List<LineSeriesData>    // <--- WRONG TYPE
```

---

To prevent errors like this, use a view-model:

**RevenueModel.cs**    (view model)

```
  public class RevenueModel
  {
      public List<AreaSeriesData> UsaData { get; set; }
      public List<AreaSeriesData> RussiaData { get; set; }
  }
```

**ReportsController.cs**

```
 public ActionResult Revenue()
 {
      RevenueModel model = new RevenueModel
      {
          // ... add data here
      };

      return View(model);      // passes the view-model into the view
 }
```

**Revenue.cshtml**    (uses view model)

```
  @model RevenueModel

   Series = new List<Series>
            {
                new LineSeries
                {
                    Name = "Tokyo",
                    Data = Model.UsaData     // <--- FROM VIEW MODEL
                }
            }
```

All the C# calculations can be moved from the view into the view-model. This makes for much cleaner code, and fewer errors at runtime.

Comment: I believe I tried to switch types when reading from the API doc but changing back to the AreaSeriesData  datatype solved the problem. The data used here is just from the Highcharts documentation but I will use view-models when using actual data. Thank you again for the feedback!